# Running asymptote code in latex

Tags: asymptote

Using some tutorial on the [Art of Problem solving forum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Asymptote:_Advanced_Configuration) on Asymptote, 
I was able to use Asymptote code inline with my Latex like  so

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
\begin{asy}
    include graph;
    size(1inch);
    filldraw(circle((0,0),1),yellow,black);
    fill(circle((-.3,.4),.1),black);
    fill(circle((.3,.4),.1),black);
    draw(arc((0,0),.5,-140,-40));
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
```

However, many of my diagrams will be far more complex than this meaning the asymptote will be longer. Is there a way I can include a link in the latex code to the asymptote script so that the latex system will automatically insert the generated picture there.

i.e. I would like something like

```
  \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
    \compile-code{smiley.asy}
  \end{figure}
```

so that the usual compilation process of latex using asymptote

```
#!/bin/bash
xelatex -shell-escape synopses.tex
asy syn*.asy
xelatex -shell-escape synopses.tex
```

works as before.

Note: I know a long way around, would be to generate the pictures separately and then include them using `includegraphics`, but this method
would be neater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. I prefer to use the `asypictureB` package. One very simple-minded possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myasy-1.tex}
\begin{asypicture}{}
    include graph;
    size(1inch);
    filldraw(circle((0,0),1),yellow,black);
    fill(circle((-.3,.4),.1),black);
    fill(circle((.3,.4),.1),black);
    draw(arc((0,0),.5,-140,-40));
\end{asypicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \input{myasy-1.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you run this with `pdflatex -shell-escape` (say), you'll get

[image]

As long as you do not change the file `myasy-1.tex`, the picture won't be recompiled.